# Estou deletando todo meu carrinho

Tags: javascript, array, react

```
function RemoverProduto(id){
    const filterCart = cart.filter(
      cartItem => cart.indexOf(cartItem) !== id
      )
      setCart(filterCart)
}
```

*aqui está meu card do carrinho*

```
export const Carrinho = () => {
    const {cart } = useContext(GlobalStateContext);

    return(
        <>
            <input></input>
            <input></input>
            {cart.map((cartItem) => ( 
                <CarrinhoCard 
                    key={cartItem.id} 
                    id={cartItem.id}
                    qty_stock={cartItem.qty_stock}
                    qty_order={cartItem.qty_order} 
                    name={cartItem.name} 
                    price={cartItem.price}/>
                    ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

*Pesquisei muito em como remover apenas um item do array do carrinho mas não consegui achar nada que funcionasse no meu código*

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

você já tentou da seguinte forma?

```
function RemoverProduto(id){
    const filterCart = cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== id);
      setCart(filterCart)
}
```

porque da forma como você está fazendo, *indexOf(cartItem)* vai retornar uma posição, logo, por exemplo, *cart.2* ou *cart.0* vai ser sempre diferente de *id* e por isso ele está excluindo todos os itens.